# How to remove update date function in data file of mail merge?

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-crm-2011, mailmerge

I've inserted a date field in mail merge and set it to the automatically update. But when I dispatch the data file from the original mail merge the automatically update functionality of the date doesn't removed. But I want to remove it automatically as well as the user dispatch the data file from the mail merge.

Please give your kind suggestions to remove the automatically update functionality on date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the date field inside a { QUOTE } field, e.g.

```
{ QUOTE { DATE } }
```

Where both pairs of {} are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert in Windows Word using ctrl-F9.

Comment: Thank You for your assistance very first it really looks helpless but a few RND help to work on it.